# Why download Service doesn't work?

Tags: java, android, file, background

#### I have following code:

```
package com.mobilinga.video_vr;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;


public class DownloadService extends IntentService {
    public static final int UPDATE_PROGRESS = 8344;
    File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "MyCameraVideo");
    private String CHANNEL_ID = "ID";
    private int notificationId = 55;

    public DownloadService() {
        super("DownloadService");
        Log.i("devoloTest", "DownloadService");

    }

    public static void unzip(File zipFile, File targetDirectory) throws IOException {
        ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(
                new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFile)));
        try {
            ZipEntry ze;
            int count;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
            while ((ze = zis.getNextEntry()) != null) {
                File file = new File(targetDirectory, ze.getName());
                File dir = ze.isDirectory() ? file : file.getParentFile();
                if (!dir.isDirectory() && !dir.mkdirs())
                    throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to ensure directory: " +
                            dir.getAbsolutePath());
                if (ze.isDirectory())
                    continue;
                FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    while ((count = zis.read(buffer)) != -1)
                        fout.write(buffer, 0, count);
                } finally {
                    fout.close();
                }
            /* if time should be restored as well
            long time = ze.getTime();
            if (time > 0)
                file.setLastModified(time);
            */
            }
        } finally {
            zis.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("devoloTest", "onHandleIntent");
        String urlToDownload = intent.getStringExtra("url");
        Log.i("devoloTest", " " + urlToDownload);
        long fileLength = 0;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlToDownload);
            Log.i("Test", "URL is " + urlToDownload);
            URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "identity");
            connection.connect();
            SettingManager settingManager = new SettingManager(this);

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            File file = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator + settingManager.getVideoType() + File.separator + "v2.zip");
            Log.i("Test", "URL is " + file.getPath());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(file);

            // this will be useful so that you can show a typical 0-100% progress bar
            fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

            Log.i("Test", "FileLength is" + fileLength);
            byte data[] = new byte[32768];
            long total = 0;
            settingManager.setLoadingStatusByCurrentSettings(SettingManager.LoadingStatus.LOADING);
            int count;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
                total += count;
                Log.i("Test", "count is" + count);
                showProgressNotification((int) total / (1024 * 1024), (int) (fileLength / (1024 * 1024)));
                output.write(data, 0, count);

            }
            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            File outputDirectory = new File(mediaStorageDir, settingManager.getVideoType());
            if (!outputDirectory.exists())
                outputDirectory.mkdirs();
            showUnzipNotification();
            unzip(file, outputDirectory);
            file.delete();
            settingManager.setLoadingStatusByCurrentSettings(SettingManager.LoadingStatus.DONE);
            showDoneNotification();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void showProgressNotification(int total, int fileLength) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Loading a video")
                .setContentText(total + "/" + fileLength + " MB")
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setProgress(total, fileLength, false)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private void showUnzipNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentTitle("Loading a video")
                .setContentText("File is unzipping")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }

    private void showDoneNotification() {
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText("Loading a video is done")
                .setContentTitle("Done")
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

#### Logs output:

> 04-12 14:56:31.463 15920-15920/com.mobilinga.mob360 I/devoloTest: DownloadService
>       04-12 14:56:31.469 15920-25109/com.mobilinga.mob360 I/devoloTest: onHandleIntent
>       04-12 14:56:31.470 15920-25109/com.mobilinga.mob360 I/devoloTest:  https://myFile.zip
>       04-12 14:56:31.470 15920-25109/com.mobilinga.mob360 I/Test: URL is https://myFile.zip
>       04-12 14:56:31.856 15920-25109/com.mobilinga.mob360 I/Test: URL is /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCameraVideo/480_en/v2.zip

It seems loading didn't started.
Url is valid, and permissions are granted.

Comment: did you register your `DownloadService` in manifest file

Comment: Yes, I  registered in manifest